# PHP Manager IIS fails to install on Windows Server 2016

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2016

I have recently installed Windows Server 2016 and I'm trying to get my IIS 10 set-up to create a site.
The PHP 5.6.30 installed just fine, but the *PHP Manager 1.2*, *WinCache 1.3 for PHP 5.6* and *CGI* didn't install!

The dialog image:
 [image: http://i.imgur.com/9aAa48o.png]

The PHP Manager log: http://pastebin.com/Y9Ud1XUU

The WebPI log: http://pastebin.com/H13fJU0Z

I've tried setting the [MajorVersion to 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216228/php-manager-for-iis-fails-to-install) (and other values), but the installer still fails. I have .NET 4.5> installed.

Comment: https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases With the new 2.0 release, there is no need to hack the registry key again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install fails because the Cgi facility is not installed and as I discovered cannot be installed via WPI. Go to Control Panel and into Windows Programs and Features. Use the traditional method of adding Cgi to Iis by checking the box and then install. Revisit WPI again and any installs that depended on Cgi will now install.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Programs and Features and ensure the .NET Framework 3.5 is installed, then try the PHP manager installation program again. This worked for me.